# Bootstrap tagsInput how to catch event on tag click

Tags: jquery, events, bootstrap-tags-input

I've a page with JQuery and some text input fields with bootstrap tagsinput. I'm using the great typeahead feature but I would like to catch the event when user clicks on the tag within the input field, I mean the click on the tag text not on the x button for removing it.

I've added this script :

```
    $('span.label-info').click(function() {
            destination_base = 'xxxxx';
            window.location.href = destination_base + $(this).text();
            return false;
    });
```

as I've seen the class of the span containing the tag text is "tag label label-info"

But the behaviour is really strange. When I add the data-role='tagsinput' to the input field, the event is catched but I could not use anymore the x to remove the tag.
If I remove the data-role, the x is working but the tag click not.
I've seen on web there is some conflict between this data-role and jQuery listener but I do not know really how to get these 2 events working at the same time, I mean the tag click and the x click.

Any idea ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please upload a snippet at JSfiddle,it would be helpful to see your problem there.

Comment: Is there any way to assign an `id` for the `span tag` generated?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a workaround but i did:

```
$(".tag").on("click", function () {
    //your code
});
```

Just make sure you do not use the class "tag" anywhere else.